# Why even though I sliced my original DataFrame and assigned it to another variable, my original DataFrame still changed values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, variables, slice

I am trying to calculate a portfolio's daily total price, by multiplying weights of each asset with the daily price of the assets.

Currently I have a DataFrame `tw` which is all zeros except for the dates that I want to re-balance, which holds my assets weights. What I would like to do is for each month, populate the zeros with the weights I am trying to re-balance with, till the next re-balancing date, and so on and so forth.

My code:

```
df_of_weights = tw.loc[dates_to_rebalance[13]:]

temp_date = dates_to_rebalance[13]
counter = 0
for date in df_of_weights.index:
    if date.year == temp_date.year and date.month == temp_date.month:
        if date.day == temp_date.day:
            pass
        else:
            df_of_weights.loc[date] = df_of_weights.loc[temp_date].values
    counter += 1
    temp_date = dates_to_rebalance[13+counter]
```

I understand that if you slice your DataFrame and assign it to a variable (`df_of_weights`), changing the values of said variable would not affect the original DataFrame. However, the values in `tw` changed. Have been searching for an answer online for a while now and am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `copy` in order to fix the problem such that:

```
df_of_weights = tw.loc[dates_to_rebalance[13]:].copy()
```

The problem is slicing provides view instead of copy. The issue is still open.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15631

Comment: I understand that making a copy would fix the problem, but shouldn't slicing the DataFrame in this case technically work as well?

Comment: I updated my answer. Due to that issue, I always use copy. I suggest the same.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help.